# How can I remove the proguard feature of the model registered with sharedprefrences

Tags: java, android, gson, sharedpreferences, proguard

I have some pojo classes in my application and proguard was open before the update, now I added the keep class properties to the proguard rules for these models.. but I was saving the data as shared prefrences with json/gson.. now when I want to pull the data, the variable names come as a, b, c.. how can i fix this

```
public class WaterModel {
    private int id;
    private String date;
    private int waterMl;
    private float waterPercent;
}
```

```
      Gson gson = new Gson();
      String json = sharedPreferences.getString(WATER_LIST, null);
      Log.d(TAG, "dailyWater " + json);
      Type type = new TypeToken<List<WaterModel>>() {}.getType();
      List<WaterModel> modelList = gson.fromJson(json, type);
```

result:

```
[{"a":1, "b":"20/07/2022", "c":750,"d":12.5}]
```

Room Database

```
  for (int i = 0; i < modelList.size(); i++) {
                            DailyWater dailyWater = new DailyWater();
                            dailyWater.setDayId(daycurrent.getId());
                            dailyWater.setDate(formatDatev1(modelList.get(i).getDate()));
                            dailyWater.setWaterMl(modelList.get(i).getWaterMl());
                            dailyWater.setWaterPercent(modelList.get(i).getWaterPercent());
                            dailyWater.setTime(milliseconds(modelList.get(i).getDate()));
                            dailyWaterDao.insertDailyWater(dailyWater);    
                }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have saved model class as string so unfortunately you can not do anything for already saved json string in shared preferenc however I would suggest to keep **WaterModel** class so next time when you will save you will get same variable name as in model class.

But you can't do anything for already saved string so try to override that json string in preference.

```
-keep class com.app.model.** { *; }
```

Comment: but i need to get this data.. can i do it as a, b, c?

Comment: Yes you can debug and check that data manually in selected device but you can not get data for all the users

Comment: Will the variables corresponding to each line be in the form of a, b, c, for example, if date coincides with the variable a in the first json object, will it be the same in the 100th line / object or will it be confused?

Comment: If it is in sequence then you will get all data in sequence but first, try to debug that in one user and check all data are in sequence or not

Comment: I tried a few data on myself but I don't know how it will be in most of them.. Also what can I use instead of get methods How can I call the letter "a" corresponding to "date"?

Comment: `-keep class com.appname.model.**{ *; }`

`-keep,allowoptimization,allowshrinking public class com.appname.model.*`

Comment: what is the difference between them? I want to disable all under model package name